# Why build a .deb package vs simply including files?

Tags: package-management, deb, programming

I'm confused as to why you would create a .deb package vs simply putting your program in a folder + additional files and writing an install script.

What are the value of packages?

Comment: 1. They make it easier to remove your program and associated files. 2. They make it easier to upgrade your program. 3. They let you declare dependencies on other packages so that they will be automatically installed when your package is installed.

Comment: 4. they let you declare with what your software is *not* compatible 5. they bring a straightforward, safe and reversible update methodology that also incorporates your dependency versions 6. You want your executables to end up in your $path, otherwise calling your software is going to be complicated, and impossible to do correctly from other software, 7. very few system software things are actually containable in a single directory, but have configuration, data and libraries in different directory than executables.

Comment: Things like appimage and flatpak try to make everything self contained, I was curious if there is a downside to doing the same thing by including all the libraries in your executable directory.

Comment: The .deb package doesn't really look required to make a distributal program but I see how it might be useful in terms of dependencies. Which is honestly a huge problem with Linux in general.

Comment: Because, over the course of years of Software Development, we have learned that "there's a better way".

Comment: AppImage things do very similar things to .deb, honestly, and are *not* just a directory: they define a "platform requirement", which is very similar to dependencies in debian packages. Essentially, appimages are closer to "overly broadly scoped" debian packages (which debian developers would rather split into multiple packages to avoid having the same things around multiple times) than to "flat directories"

Comment: and I'd be highly interested in how you AppImage-package a central system service, such as the services necessary to make AppImages run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that the *primary reason* for the existence of a Linux distribution is to, well, *distribute* a coherent set of packages. And since you don't want to get stuck on the same versions for all eternity, you also need a way to upgrade. And since you don't want to have software installed you don't need, you need a way to select which packages you want. And since you cannot predict the future, you will need a way to change this selection later, i.e., install or remove packages. And since reuse is one of the basic tenets of software engineering, packages depend on other packages, so you need a way to handle those dependencies.

All this leads to the creation of a package management system.

A package management system provides

- *Dependency Management*: a package can declare that it needs another package to work. In fact, most package managers are more powerful than this, and a package can actually declare that it needs one out of a set of packages with specific versions to work. When installing a package, the package management system automatically makes sure that all dependencies are met, and crucially that all dependencies of all currently installed packages continue to be met.
- *Installation*: a package management system provides a uniform, standardized way of installing packages, while making sure all dependencies are met and no conflicts with already installed packages arise. Generally, every program has a different way of installing it (an interactive graphical installer, an interactive CLI installer, a batch CLI installer, `make install`, `./install.sh`, copying files by hand), a package manage system has a standardized way (`apt install`).
- *Removal*: a package management system provides a uniform, standardized way of uninstalling packages, while making sure that this doesn't break any currently installed package. It also can automatically uninstall dependencies that are no longer needed. The situation without a package manager is similar to installation but even worse, since many programs don't provide a way to uninstall them at all.
- *Update*: this is similar to installation but harder, since many programs don't provide a way to update them. And, of course, during an update, the package manager needs to take care that the overall system is consistent at all times.

In general, we can say that the purpose of a package management system is to provide a *consistent system* where the individual parts of the system are *non-cooperative*. In other words, the different packages don't need to know about each other, it is the package management system's job to ensure they work well together.